# Tool to create css and div from template layout

Tags: css, html, user-interface

I'm looking for a tool that can help me generate css / div information through a UI / live preview.

For example, I'd like to just create the UI (top part of the image) and have the tool provide the css (bottom part of the image).

I've seen a lot of stuff for webpage layouts, but what I'm looking for is for "components".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Download HTTrack from
   [httrack.com/page/2](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/).
2. Install the .exe and run the app.
3. Provide the link of the page you want HTML and CSS for and start
       copying code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Brackets".

You have few features like :

1. Code Hints from PSD
2. Inline editors
3. Live preview

Link : http://brackets.io/